# Locked out of iPhone. Don't want to restore

Tags: ios, apple-id

After 6 months of not going on my phone, I have forgotten my (complex (I feel like an idiot)) password. Is there any way that I could save the files on it to a computer or talk to Apple or my service provider (because I could prove the Apple ID on the phone is mine) and have the password removed? I just don't want to have to lose everything I have on it by doing a full restore. Any possibilities? I have never backed it up to iCloud or any computer so I would have to delete everything on it. It is an iPhone 5 with ios 7 or the first one after seve

Comment: If you haven't used your phone for 6 months, is there really anything on it which you can't be without?

Comment: It's nothing I need, but there's stuff that's saved on it that I could never get again. I have stuff saved to my notes, I have pictures, text messages, etc.

Comment: maybe I missed it in your question, what iPhone is it with what ios?

Comment: iphone 5 with ios 7 or the first one after seven I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few iPhone lockscreen bypass procedures. Though they greatly depend on exactly which firmware is on the device, otherwise, I have a feeling your S.O.L.

http://www.wikihow.com/Bypass-iPhone-Passcode

Comment: yup, I had upgraded to ios 7 :/ nice answer though

Comment: Was the device jailbroken? I remember reading (a while ago) about a way to bypass device lock requiring jailbreak. (My be obsolete though)

Comment: Was not jailbroken

Comment: Just saw this on my Twitter Feed: https://twitter.com/sherif_hashim/status/462982431432519683

Comment: Interesting. Everything was already blocked on my phone so I couldn't use Siri or any of that, and it only gives you access to the contacts list, but It's still a flaw

Answer (score -1):

You could even try going to - iforgot.apple.com - from there you can reset your password and get into your iphone.

Comment: I believe that is only for resetting your Apple ID password. I need help with my lock screen password, to unlock the phone itself - not related to the Apple ID.